# deleting a line in a .txt file without using another file or array in C++

Tags: c++, file, text-files

the professor gave told us to delete a line in a txt file without the help of another file or an array,
i tried to replace the line with backspace but it print the BS character instead

```
void rem()
{
    fstream f("test.txt");
    f.seekp(3, ios_base::beg);
    f.write("\b",sizeof(char));
    f.close();
}
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

i want to remove 2

```
1
3
4
5
```

after searching for few hours i found  that everyone use another file or a vector or the try to replay the line with BS like me.

EDIT:

this is the correct code:

```
void skip_line(std::fstream& f)
{
    char c;
    f.get(c);
    f.ignore(50, '\n');
}
```

```
void getpos(int& readpos, int& writepos)
{
    std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    skip_line(f);
    writepos = f.tellg();
    skip_line(f);
    readpos = f.tellg();
    f.close();
}
```

```
void rem()
{
    int writepos, readpos, length, newSize;
    std::fstream f;

    getpos(readpos, writepos);
    f.open("test.txt");
    length = readpos - writepos;
    f.seekg(readpos);
    

    for (char c; f.get(c);)
    {
        f.seekg(writepos);
        if (c != '\n') f.put(c);
        readpos++;
        writepos++;
        f.seekg(readpos);
    }
    f.close();
    //fs::path p = "test.txt"
    newSize = fs::file_size("test.txt") - length;
    fs::resize_file("test.txt", newSize);

}
```

the rusult:

befor

```
111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
```

after

```
111111
333333
444444
555555
```

Comment: When you say "_or an array_", does that also include `std::vector`s?

Comment: would overwriting with a space be acceptable for the assignment?

Comment: With these restrictions you'll need to read one character at a time until you find line 3, `seekp` to the position returned by `tellg`.  Then read forward to line 4.  Now loop reading characters and writing them out until end of file.  Finally, truncate the file.

Answer (score 2):

Backspace will not do what you hoped for. A backspace character takes up one `char` just like any other character. When printed on devices capable of moving the cursor backwards, that's what'll happen. It's just a visual thing and it does not work with files.

Since you are not allowed to use another file or arrays, I'm going to assume that `std::vector`s and `std::string`s are also forbidden so I suggest shifting everything down in the file, one `char` at a time, to overwrite the line to be removed.

- You will need a function like `std::getline` which is capable of reading a line from a stream into a `std::string` - but you do not need to store any data so we can call it `skip_line`. It could look like this:

  ```
  std::istream& skip_line(std::istream& is) {
      // read until reading fails or a newline is read:
      for(char ch; is.get(ch) && ch != '\n';);
      return is;
  }
  ```
- When you've opened the file, call `skip_line` until you've reached the line you want to remove. If you want to remove line 2, call `skip_line` 1 time. If you instead want to remove line 3, call `skip_line` 2 times.
- The *get* (`f.tellg()`) position in the stream is now where you should start writing when you move everyting in the file back to overwrite the line to be removed. Store this position in a variable called `writepos`.
- Call `skip_line` one time. The *get* position is now where you should start reading when moving the contents of the file. Store this position in a variable called `readpos`.
- Calculate and store the length of the line to be removed: `lenght_of_line_to_be_removed = readpos - writepos`.
- Now, you need to read one `char` at a time from the `readpos` position and write that `char` to the `writepos` position. It could look like this:

  ```
  f.seekg(readpos);           // set the _get_ position where we should read from
  for(char ch; f.get(ch);) {  // loop for as long as you can read a char
      f.seekp(writepos);      // set the _put_ position where you should write to
      f.put(ch);              // ...and write the char
      writepos += 1;          // step both positions forward
      readpos += 1;           // -"-
      f.seekg(readpos);       // set the new _get_ position
  }
  ```
- When the above is done, everything is "shifted down" in the file - but the size of the file will still be the same as it was before:

```
original: 1 2 3 4 5
after   : 1 3 4 5 5
```

If you use C++17 or newer, you can use the standard functions [`std::filesystem::file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) and [`std::filesystem::resize_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file) to fix this. Remember that you stored `lenght_of_line_to_be_removed` above. If you use a version of C++ that does not have `std::filesystem`, you need to use some platform specific function. Posix systems have the `truncate` function that can be used for this.

Comment: so i should move the line to the end of the file and then resize it to remove the line

Comment: @zombie No, there is no need to move (copy) the line since it's supposed to be removed. I added a little visual detail to show what it'll look like after the copying to overwrite the line to be removed has been done.

Comment: i tried to do it but it didnt work. i edited my question please take a look

Comment: @zombie In programming reading/understanding is key. I wrote the answer like I did so you couldn't implement it without actuaully having understood the algorithm. I see that you missed a few key points which in turn makes it impossible to understand the solution I'm suggesting. If you read my notes (carefully) while drawing the two different positions on a piece of paper, you should get an "aha" moment eventually.